# pass state data from child to nested component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

```js
const Child = ({ ChildIndex }) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState();

  <FlatList
    contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
    ref={flatListRef}
    scrollEnabled
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    data={videos}
    onMomentumScrollEnd={(e) => {
      setIndex(Math.round(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / width));
    }}
    onEndReachedThreshold={Platform.OS === "ios" ? 0 : 1}
  />;
};
```

```js
const Parent = () => {
  const [currentChildIndex, setCurrentChildIndex] = useState();
  <Child ChildIndex={ChildIndex} />;
};
```

I wanted to get the updated `currentChildIndex`, in the parent component. It shows the index when it first loads but it doesn't update afterward. Tried to look useState hook but not luck

Comment: Where is this "ChildIndex" initialized?

Comment: I was trying to pass it as a setter prop, updated the ChildIndex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass `setCurrentChildIndex` instead:

```
const Parent = () => {
  const [currentChildIndex, setCurrentChildIndex] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("CurrentChildIndex has been updated", currentChildIndex);
  }, [currentChildIndex]);
  return <Child setCurrentChildIndex={setCurrentChildIndex} />;
};
```

and consume it in your `Child` component instead of `setIndex`

```
const Child =({setCurrentChildIndex})=>{


    <FlatList
      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
      ref={flatListRef}
      scrollEnabled
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      data={videos}
      onMomentumScrollEnd={e => {
      setCurrentChildIndex(Math.round(e.nativeEvent.contentOffset.x / width));
    }} 
    onEndReachedThreshold={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 1}
    />
/>
}
```

Comment: How can I update const `[currentChildIndex, setCurrentChildIndex] = useState()`
with `setCurrentChildIndex` in Parent component then?

Comment: You don need to update it, checkout the edit...

Comment: I am still getting the result only once. When I ´console.log(currentChildIndex)`, it only shows once

Comment: `onMomentumScrollEnd ` is called once... that was all : ))